# My while loop won't exit even though the input is correct

Tags: python

My `while` loop just keeps on going even though I input y, yes, n, or no.

```
import random

def rollDice():
    diceRoll = random.randint(1,6)
    return diceRoll
    
def reRollDie1():
    reRollDie1 = input("Would you like to re roll die 1?")
    reRollDie1.lower()
    
    while reRollDie1 != "yes" or reRollDie1 != "y" or reRollDie1 != "no" or reRollDie1 != "n":
        reRollDie1 = input("Sorry that answer is invalid please try again. Would you like to re-roll die 1? ")         
reRollDie1()
```

OUTPUT:

> Sorry that answer is invalid please try again. Would you like to re-roll die 1? no
>
> Sorry that answer is invalid please try again. Would you like to re-roll die 1? yes
>
> Sorry that answer is invalid please try again. Would you like to re-roll die 1? yes

Comment: Consolidating your multiple inequalities to an `in` can help you better understand what's going on.

Comment: I think you just want `while reRollDie1 in ('yes', 'y'):`. That way, the condition will be false if the user enters `n` or `no`.

Comment: Thats not true @SumnerEvans OP wants to check for valid input it can `yes`, `y`, `n` or `no`.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking all the options with `or`. Since each is an inequality test, and each option is different from the others, the condition will always be true. I would instead suggest a test such as `reRollDie1 not in {"yes", "y", "no", "n"}`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if this is any better but I just added an if statement inside my while loop.

Comment: if reRollDie1 == "yes" or reRollDie1 == "y":
            rollDie1 = rollDice()
            break

Comment: There's an important difference between this test and the one in your question. Equality tests with `==` can be meaningfully combined with `or`, but the inequality tests with `!=` would need `and` instead. Bear in mind your variable has the same value in each subtest. This relates to [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) in logic.